# Nestjs Authentication Project: "statusCode": 401, "message": "Unauthorized"

Tags: nestjs, basic-authentication, passport-local

I am learning NestJS. I tried to build a basic authentication project using NestJS and passport-local. But I got the error of "statusCode": 401,"message": "Unauthorized".

Here is the app module file:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { UserService } from './users/users.services';
    
@Module({
   imports: [UsersModule, AuthModule],
   controllers: [AppController],
   providers: [UserService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the app controller file:

```js
import { Controller, Get, Post, Request, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
    
@Controller("app")
export class AppController {
  constructor() { }
   
  @Post()
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard("local"))
  async login(@Request() req) {
   // console.log(req.user);-----undefined
    return "This is private msg";
  }
}
```

Now here is the user data file:

```js
export class User {
    name: string;
    password: string;
    age: number;
}
```

Now here is the user service file:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { User } from "./users.data";
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    public users: User[] = [
        {
            "name": "user1",
            "password": "admin",
            "age": 10
        },
        {
            "name": "user2",
            "password": "admin",
            "age": 102
        },
        {
            "name": "user3",
            "password": "admin",
            "age": 103
        },
        {
            "name": "user4",
            "password": "admin",
            "age": 104
        },
    ];
    
    async getUserByName(userName: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
        return this.users.find(user => user.name === userName);
    }
}
```

Here is the user module file:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './users.services';
   
@Module({
    imports: [],
    controllers: [],
    providers: [UserService],
    exports: [UserService]
})
    
export class UsersModule { }
```

here is the Auth passport local file:

```js
import { Injectable, Request, UnauthorizedException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { Strategy } from "passport-local";
import { UserService } from '../users/users.services';
import { User } from '../users/users.data';
    
@Injectable()
export class PassportlocalStragey extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
        super();
    }
    
    
        async validate(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
        console.log('Here I go');
        const user = await this.userService.getUserByName(username);
        console.log('Got user', user);

        if (user == undefined) throw new UnauthorizedException();

        if (user && user.password === password) {
            return user;
        } else {
            console.log('Password mismatch');
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Auth module file:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportlocalStragey } from './passportlocal.auth';
import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { UserService } from 'src/users/users.services';
    
@Module({
    imports: [UsersModule, PassportModule],
    controllers: [],
    providers: [PassportlocalStragey],
    exports: []
})
    
export class AuthModule { }
```

Here is the output of the error:

```json
{
  "statusCode": 401,
  "message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

[image]

Where is the problem? How can I solve this? Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `PassportlocalStragey` the validation method should be

```js
async validate(username: string, password: string)
```

not `validateUser`.

EDIT:
I have reproduced your code locally as it was bugging me. It works for me, here are my classes that might be slightly different from yours:

`AuthModule`

```js
@Module({
  imports: [PassportModule],
  providers: [UserService, PassportLocalStrategy],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

`PassportLocalStrategy`

```js
@Injectable()
export class PassportLocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    super();
  }

  async validate(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    console.log('Here I go');
    const user = await this.userService.getUserByName(username);
    console.log('Got user', user);

    if (user == undefined) throw new UnauthorizedException();

    if (user && user.password === password) {
      return user;
    } else {
      console.log('Password mismatch');
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class LocalGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {}
```

`AppController`

```js
@Controller('api')
export class AppController {
  constructor() {}

  @Post('login')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
  // @UseGuards(LocalGuard)
  login(@Req() req): any {
    return req.user;
  }
}
```

I did add `LocalGuard` class to the `PassportLocalStrategy` file. The guard on the route works for both `@UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))` or `@UseGuards(LocalGuard)`.

`AppModule`

```js
@Module({
  imports: [AuthModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks. But after correcting that I got the same "statusCode": 401,  "message": "Unauthorized" error.

Comment: Try putting the class name to the guard annotation as per edit I just made.

Comment: @UseGuards(PassportlocalStragey)) : using this, It does not do any authentication.

Comment: In app controller, the console log result of (req,user) is undefined.

Comment: I will check your code once again but apart from those points mentioned I don't see anything wrong there :(

Comment: Reproduced locally, works for me. Will update answer as I made a mistake, the strategy itself is not a guard.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. I don't know why I face same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246706/discussion-between-shan-and-pes).

Comment: it works. but need to change the input field in postman: "name" to "username". I tried with the "name". Thank You.

Comment: glad to hear. you can actually configure the field names in the constructor of the strategy IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

Passport expects you to send `username` and `password` as properties of `req.body`. You are sending `name` and `password`. If you want to use `name` instead of `username` you need to pass `usernameField: 'name'` to the `super()` call in your `PassportlocalStragey #constructor`

Comment: Thank You. Now I can understand the whole thing about my authentication error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you. Now i understand that nest js is expecting the username to be username. so if you want to use email you need to specify it it the super().
constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
super({
usernameField: 'email',
});
}

Comment: needs formatting and styling